# mov instruction operands type

Tags: assembly, nasm, operands

this is a part of code that does multiplying 2 and 3:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
mov al,'3'
sub al, '0'
mov bl, '2'
sub bl, '0'
mul bl
add al, '0'
;first question -> 
mov [res], al
mov ecx,msg
mov edx, len
mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80
;second question ->
mov ecx,res
mov edx, 1
mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80
mov eax,1 ;system call number (sys_exit)
int 0x80
section .data
msg db "The result is:", 0xA,0xD
len equ $- msg
segment .bss
res resb 1
```

in above code:

1. why should we use `mov [res], al` and don't use `mov res, al`?
2. why should we use `mov ecx,res` and don't use `mov ecx,[res]`?

****update

i know that one is address and other is value of that,but I don't know why ...

Comment: One takes the address, the other value stored in that address

Comment: tnx my friend.i know that but i dont know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a name for the assembler, nothing more than symbol denoting a value.
You already know that the value of `res` is the address of the first byte after it.
We informally say that `res` is the address of the variable *res*.

Under this consideration the instruction `mov res, ecx` make no sense, desugared it is equivalent to `mov <a number>, ecx`.
A concrete example: `mov 0x12345678, ecx` - moving into an immediate makes no sense.

`mov ecx, res` makes sense, it loads `ecx` with the address of *res*.
We need its address and not its value because `sys_write` writes a stream of bytes into a file (*stdout* in your case) - it is nothing like the functions to print numbers found in high-level languages.
In fact, the *single digit* result of the multiplication is converted into a string by the mean of `add al, '0'`.
After the conversion `sys_write` is used to write the *string* (not the number!) into *stdout*.
Since `sys_write` deals with streams of bytes it expects in `ecx` the address of the first byte to write.
You can take a look at the [C wrapper](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) to check the type of the arguments: `const void*` for the second argument.
So an address must be given (`mov ecx, res`) not a value<sup>1</sup> (`mov ecx, [res]`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Beware that the distinction between addresses and values is purely semantic, there is no such division in assembly.